# RDS SQL Server AWS - Dúvida sobre alterar classe da instancia BD

Tags: sql, servidor, amazon-aws

Preciso mudar a classe da instancia do banco de dados, pois utilizo a "micro" e preciso alterar para uma instancia com recursos maiores.
Minha dúvida é se ao alterar, eu perco meu banco de dados atual? Esse é um banco MS SQL Server em produção, então não posso correr o risco, alguém sabe me informar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não irá perder mas como garantia, faça um snapshot antes.
Durante o upgrade, você terá um período de instabilidade e indisponibilidade da base.

Um caminho sem indisponibilidade é fazer o snapshot e a partir dele criar uma nova instância, a qual substituirá a primeira.